# How can I get all music out off iTunes

Tags: macos, itunes-10

How can I get all the music that iTunes can play, out of a Mac computer.

including playlists, and without using an iPod (or similar device).

(Its  lot of software that can do this, but most have some restrictions)

**Answer to comments (E1)**

> You can burn CDs from the playlists without leaving iTunes on the Mac

Not all tracks AFAIK (Depends on format, if it is inside/outside the iTunes and/or license).

Another thing is that I might want to export all tracks in a playlist.

> Would transferring your iTunes library on Mac

Perhaps as a first step, but it doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: You are taking your music off the Mac, but where are you hoping to move it all?

Comment: Somewhere I can burn CDs from the playlists:-)  . . (Primarily from some software on Windows)

Comment: You can burn CDs from the playlists without leaving iTunes on the Mac, if that's all you wanted to do.  Just select the playlist and choose "Burn Playlist to Disc" from the File menu.  :)

Comment: Would transferring your iTunes library on Mac --> iTunes on Windows be something you are interested in?

Comment: Replies to comments at end ofpost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the files from ~/Music/ to a disk. They aren't hidden or anything.

Playlists need to be exported.